# Air Admittance Valve is stuck and there is very little pipe to work with. How do I replace?

Tags: drain, sink

I don't have much pipe to work with here and the Air Admittance valve is closed shut. I had it working for about 15 minutes and the water flowed like a river, so it is definitely the air admittance valve that is the culprit. I tried to unscrew it and it will not budge. I don't see any glue on it, so I'm hoping it is not glued and after a night of silicone maybe I can get it to turn in the morning... Maybe there is a way to fix/repair the existing one?

I'm hoping there is a way to remove the valve and not have to replace the entire drain starting at the back wall. Any suggestions on how to remove/fix the Air Admittance valve.. or if there is a way to unscrew it, would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance and Happy Turkey Day!

[image: Air Admittance Valve (1 of 2)(from below] [[image: Air Admittance Valve (2 of 2)]][24]

Comment: "I tried to unscrew it and it will not budge" ... with a 2' pipe wrench? Channel locks ain't gonna do it.

Comment: I'd bet on some clown building it that way in the first place, and I don't see any sign that it improved useable space in the cabinet by doing so.

Comment: Just for education, since I've never seen one: Is the AAV supposed to be a substitute for a missing/clogged-and-unclearable vent stack? Or is there another reason for it?

Comment: AAVs (Mechanical Vents) are typically installed instead of a vent to outside. I dislike them intensely because they fail, regularly, and vents to outside fail very rarely indeed. Your system still needs at least one traditional vent (under most codes I know of), but they are commonly used in add-on or remodel additional or relocated sink scenarios where a normal vent is considered "too difficult" to install (or the builder or remodeler is not planning to live there and it's purely that it's cheaper to do...)

Comment: A better install is to run them inside the wall up above sink level to an access door (they have to be accessible, as they do need replacement) since that limits their exposure to liquid waste, prolonging their life. Putting them inside the cabinet is suboptimal, and if in the cabinet they should be as high as possible in it, to optimize within the bounds of starting form a suboptimal choice. I try to find a way to run a vent pipe.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks for the advice. I will try to figure out how to vent it properly over time... right now we have house guests coming tomorrow and I am OK with just replacing the vent for the week... After that I will tackle the real issue...

Comment: @keshlam, The purpose of that  breather ( not vent per se), a vent in this plumbing context is open pipe, is to let air go through but keep the smell of drain from coming up through.  Without a reasonable vent, water may not flow smoothly down the drain due to vacuum lock. Take a straw and hold it up, run water down through it and as it fills, put your finger on top part of it and the water will stop flowing down through it.  By the way nothing goes wrong with these  breathers unless some critter or its gets packed with roaches... They last 30 years

Comment: Ok, so essentially the same function as a vent pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this. As I was trying to break it free, I ended up breaking off the pipe coming out of the wall (and yes, the threads were glued). Luckily, it was after the 90 degree elbow. I made a clean cut and was able to glue a 2" pipe extender,  which allowed me to recreate the original setup. [image: 2" pipe extender]. I really had to jam the pipe extender in there (and I didn't think it would fit, but I used a little heat it fit like a glove. This did not solve my slow drain issue in the least. Nor did getting a larger air-admittance valve. What finally did the trick was using "concrete dissolver" to get rid of the blockage of concrete (that would not budge under 4000 PSI). [Concrete Dissolver - Biodegradable and neutralized by water!](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074TXXH9W). Now it runs like a river once again (and down the drain, not into the house ;-) ) Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 5):

As should be the case, and as your picture shows, it's threaded into a PVC to FPT adapter.

[image: Threads]

Remove by unscrewing the valve. Preferably use two wrenches, one to hold the adapter still so you're not torquing the drain pipe (that's what the projecting lugs on it are for) and one to unscrew the valve (that's what the projecting lugs just above its male threads are for.) You should not be able to unscrew without tools, and the replacement should be likewise tightened with tools. Use teflon tape or pipe dope on the threads.

Buy two replacements, and tape or tie the second one to the pipe for "next time."

It might delay next time if you add an additional bit of pipe so the AAV is right up by the counter - there appears to be more space than there should be there, as "higher is better" for AAV placement.

Comment: Great advice. I will get two pipe wrenches and get it corrected and extend the pipe. There is a little more room in there and I'm sure the existing one is clogged. Too late tonight to get tools, but with a little luck I will remedy that tomorrow. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Probably glued the threads in if it is threaded. Cut out and redo if that's the situation.